# How to use one driver for background and each set of scenario outline, but use new driver for different scenario outline example data?

Tags: automation, webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I am new to Cucumber and have a difficulty which might be an easy one for those who know how. So can anybody help me out? Appreciate very much!
My Feature file is something like this:

```gherkin
Background: User logged in and goes to Consumer Page as an Internal Admin 
    Given user is logged in as Internal Admin
    When user clicks on Consumer 
    Then the Consumer screen will display

@Consumer
Scenario Outline: New Application - Multiple Applicants: Verify consumer head line verification Message 
    When user select New Application from Enquiry Type
    And user enters "<NoOfApplicant>" in Number of Applicants field
    Then user should see correct Consumer "<verification>" messages for each consumer
    Examples:  
       |NoOfApplicant|verification |
       |1            |One Consumer |
       |2            |Two Consumers|
```

What I want to achieve is to use one driver session to run background and first scenario, close the driver after first scenario finishes. Open a new driver, run background, run the second scenario and close the driver.

So does anyone know how to implement this?

My current situation is:

1. Define static driver and close it after hook. the result is the
   driver been closed after background is executed, that will cause
   first scenario has no driver;
2. If I change the driver to non-static and close it after hook, then the driver will be closed and a new driver will be created for the first scenario. but not run background again and run the first scenario directly. Because the background hasn't been executed so the driver is not on the page and not yet ready to run the first scenario.
3. But if I use a static driver and don't close the driver after hook, then the second scenario will use the same driver and run the
   background again which will fail as well because the page is already
   logged in...

I am a bit hung up here. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: which version of cucumber are you using?

Comment: How is the driver closing after background steps are run, the after hook will only run after scenario is also completed? Why not just use a non-static driver which u initialize in the before hook and close in after hook?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your cookies with selenium, in the majority of cases, you'll be logged out - refreshing the state without closing the browser.

Either that, or in your log in step, check who is logged in, if it's the right user, you have already finished that step, if it's the wrong user, log out and log back in again, and if it's not logged in, just log in.

On another note:

The contents of the `Background` are always executed before every scenario within the feature file, so that shouldn't be an issue at all - the issue would be where you are closing the browser, which should be in an after hook, and opening the browser, which should be in a before hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should either

1. Run one scenario twice, using an environment variable to determine which driver to use

OR

2. Write a separate scenario for each browser and use tags to switch the driver

OR

3. Add the driver name to your example table and ensure that the driver is loaded from this before any steps that open the browser

The last solution is by far the worst